# Getting duplicate call to my define that writes to a aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files

I have the following:

```
\newif\ifabrvused
\abrvusedfalse

\def\abrv#1#2{%
  \ifabrvused\else%
    \newwrite\@loa%
    \immediate\openout\@loa=\jobname.loa%
    \write0{    Test}
    \abrvusedtrue%
  \fi%

  \@ifundefined{abrv@#1}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname abrv@#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \immediate\write\@loa{\unexpanded{\item[\textbf{#1}]#2}}%
    {#2 (\textbf{#1})}%
  }{%
  {\textbf{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

The intention is that the first time its called it opens the aux file for writing.
My problem is, that the open part (`ifabrvused\else`) is getting called twice. I was able to find out that its getting called for the first use within my `begin{abstract}` and the rest of the document? What am I missing. If its intended to do so, how can i code around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the environment `abstract` you are inside a group. `\abrvusedtrue` is a local assignment (`\let\ifabrvused\iftrue`). The switch is reset to `false` after the environment.
Use `\global\abrvusedtrue` instead.

Comment: Thanks it works. Just noticed how the line '{#2 (\textbf{#1})}%' always starts a newline before writing the text. Happen to know why?

Comment: @s093294 You have an empty line in your definition that causes the end of the previous paragraph.

Comment: \@ifundefined{abrv@#1}{% do not seem to work. Its written to aux file for both abstract and and document. I assume its the same problem, just dont know where to tell it to use global for that